# Joomla! Timezone

Tags: php, date, joomla, timezone

I'm a little confused with something: if I setup the timezone on *Joomla! Admin (Global Configuration > Location Settings > Server Time Zone)* the line below would show the date in my timezone, right?

```
$JDate = JFactory::getDate('now');
echo $JDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s', true);
```

Why I need to do this:

```
$JDate = JFactory::getDate('now', new DateTimeZone('America/Sao_Paulo'));
echo $JDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s', true);
```

I understand it wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`JFactory::getDate()` will always stay in UTC. This is good for storing dates into the database and other calculations.

For displaying a date to a user, it is recommended to use `JHtml::date()`. This will automatically use your timezone setting.

```
JHtml::date('now', 'Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

For more information and to see the code behind this function: http://docs.joomla.org/API16:JHtml/date